# Как сделать что бы при нажатии на кнопку "Жалоба" к ячейке прибавлялась единица?

Tags: php, база-данных

```
<?php 
 $mysqli_connect = mysqli_query($mysqli , "SELECT * FROM comment");
 if (isset($_POST['report'])) {
  mysqli_query($mysqli , "INSERT INTO comment(message) VALUES report = report 
  + 1");
  }
  ?>
 <section>
<?php
  while ($mysqli_fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mysqli_connect)) {
    ?>
    <p>
    <h1>
    <p><?php echo $mysqli_fetch['author']; ?></p>
    </h1>
    <p><?php echo $mysqli_fetch['pubdate']; ?></p>
    </p>
    <h2>Comment about <?php echo $mysqli_fetch['tema']; ?></h2>
    <p><?php echo $mysqli_fetch['message'] ?></p>
    <form action="get_message.php" method="POST">
        <button type="submit" name="report">Жалоба</button> 
    </form><hr>
    <?php  
}
 ?>
 <a href="index.php">Back</a>
 </section>
```

Мне нужен сам запрос к БД и как он будет выглядеть

Comment: `UPDATE comment SET report = report + 1 WHERE id = ?`

Comment: Спасибо , @ArchDemon